# Node.js + Express simplest SPA example

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, single-page-application

I'm trying to make a tiny SPA app work.

I have a following structure in my app folder:

```
/about.html
/index.html
/index.js
```

index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');

const staticHref = '/static';
const publicFolder = path.join(__dirname, '/');

app.use(staticHref, express.static(publicFolder));
app.use(staticHref, function(req, res) {
    res.send(404);
});

app.all('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('index.html', {root: publicFolder});
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('running');
});
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Homepage</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Homepage</h1>
<a href="/static/about">About</a>
</body>
</html>
```

about.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>About Us</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>About Us</h1>
<a href="/static">Home</a>
</body>
</html>
```

When I go to `http://localhost:3000/static/` it shows my homepage. But when I click the about link it throws 404 on `http://localhost:3000/static/about`

How can I resolve this issue? I want to work it as SPA (so no refresh while navigating through the pages).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an SPA, you have multiple static pages and you're basically sending all your requests to your `index` page not allowing users to go to any of your other static pages like `about`.

You need to research SPAs and how they work because that's not how they are configured. You can use a JavaScript framework (React, Angular etc.) to do this, either on the client-side or on the server-side with route matching.

- [SPA Architecture - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application)
- [SPA vs MPA - A well-written blog post](https://medium.com/@NeotericEU/single-page-application-vs-multiple-page-application-2591588efe58)
- [SPA vs MPA - A well-explained video for beginners.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F_BYg2QGsC0)